# Text doesn't show up with android:textStyle="italic"

Tags: android

Below is the XML I am using and when I use the android:textStyle="italic" attribute, the text doesn't show up.  Basically any TextView with the style SummarySubtitle will not show up.

```
    <style name="SummarySubtitle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
       <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
       <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
       <item name="android:gravity">right|center_vertical</item>
       <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
       <item name="android:paddingRight">6dp</item>
       <item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>
       <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
   </style>

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="70dp"
       android:orientation="vertical">

       <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/summary_header"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="30dp"
           android:orientation="horizontal">

           <TextView android:id="@+id/summary_title" android:text="Title"
               style="@style/SummaryTitle"/>

           <TextView android:id="@+id/summary_subtitle"
               android:text="Subtitle " style="@style/SummarySubtitle"/>

       </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/summary_subheader"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="20dp"
           android:orientation="horizontal">

          <TextView android:id="@+id/summary_min" android:text="@string/min"
              style="@style/SummaryHeader"/>

          <TextView android:id="@+id/summary_max" android:text="@string/max"
              style="@style/SummaryHeader"/>

          <TextView android:id="@+id/summary_avg" android:text="@string/avg"
              style="@style/SummaryHeader"/>

      </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/summary_values"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="20dp"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

         <TextView android:id="@+id/summary_value_min"
             android:text="$0.00" style="@style/SummaryValue"/>

         <TextView android:id="@+id/summary_value_max"
             android:text="$0.00" style="@style/SummaryValue"/>

         <TextView android:id="@+id/summary_value_avg"
             android:text="$0.00" style="@style/SummaryValue"/>

     </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: so that mean that if you remove the android:textStyle the components gets rendered?

Comment: Seems no one uses italic... or there would be more people who notice. ^^ Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 5):

All I found on the subject so far

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/843376e298e95e14

Relevant quote: "Oh yeah, I have seen that too. But when you run your app, it renders
correctly."

It doesn't show up on the layout's graphical representation but works correctly when you build and run the app.

Comment: Indeed, when I ran the app on the device the style applies correctly. Even combining it with another style, like `android:textStyle="bold|italic"` .

Comment: I have the opposite problem : it show correctly (italic) on Eclipse preview but not on my Galaxy Tab 2 device.

Comment: Strange..Its working for Galaxy Nexus device but not working for Galaxy S3 and Galaxy S2

Comment: Hi Subrat... It's been a while since I posted this answer, and it's been a while since I have programmed on Android so honestly I have no idea what's happening with the Galaxy devices :( Sorry

Answer (score -1):

try using this code:

```
adInfoTV.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE,Typeface.ITALIC);
```